# автоматизация загрузки шаблонов Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Доброго времени суток. В поисках ответа на свой вопрос набрел на подобный способ

```
function loadTemplate(path, callback) {
            var source, template;

            $.ajax({
                url: path,
                success: function (data) {
                    source = data;
                    template = Handlebars.compile(source);

                    if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback(template);
                    }
                }
            });
        };

loadTemplate('script/templateTask.html', function (template) {
        $(".one").html(template);
     });
```

И все вроде должно грузится и работать но выдает абсолютно 0 эмоций.  Ни ошибок ни результатов. Подскажите в каком направлении копать. Нужно Подтягивать шаблоны из стороннего файла и раскидывать в нужные места в нужном количестве.

Заранее спасибо.)

Comment: Приветствую Чтобы решить проблему типа "ни ошибок ни результатов" надо дебажить код. А именно, поставить брейкпоинты во всех критических точках и смотреть как код выполняется. К примеру, выполняется ли функция success, вызывается ли callback и т.п. DevTools есть в хроме, файрфоксе и т.д.

Comment: @Daniel Khoroshko Через стандартный дебагер лисы пробовал. просто перепрыгивает код и нет возможности считать значения

Comment: вопрос в том,  осуществляется ли переход на строки `callback(template);` , `$(".one").html(template);`, и т.д.

Comment: так же в Network надо посмотреть успешен ли ajax запрос и что возвращает